# Backbone collection persisting

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I rarely get stuck in JS but this time I have a feeling I did something wrong somewhere - Enlightened people, here you go :

in view1, I have :

```
    listView = new ListView({collection: listElements});
    listView.render();
```

Which is called each time listElements changes.

in ListView, the collection gets parsed to a template in the `render` method then an event is fired on click :

```
  //ListView.js
  events: {
    "click .listEl": "doStuff"
  ...
  },
  doStuff: function(e) {
    // if this is when the problem arises : this.collection at this place isn't the
    // same collection passed to ListView in view1 (or the collection in
    // the initialize() ).
    // It's actually the first value ever to be rendered with ListElements.
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you creating a new ListView each time listElements changes? Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Do you have multiple `ListView` instances bound to the same DOM element (i.e. zombie views)? Do you ever [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) your old views?

Comment: @muistooshort right on the spot. I completely forgot about Zombie events/views. I already miss Angular ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @muistooshort for the head's up.

It was due to Zombie events/views; to 'quickly' fix it, run this after you need to get rid of the view and it's bound to events.

```
  this.listView.undelegateEvents();
  $(this.listView.el).removeData().unbind();
  this.listView.$el.html('');
```

A more elegant version would be to extend Backbone.View and add a remove() method to it.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, in Backbone 1.0; I'm using a 0.9 (AMD fork), so remove() only removes the $el from the dom (doesn't call `stopListening `)